# Missing equation numbers in aligned environment inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, equations

I try to create a tabular environment containing a two-lined description on the left side of an equation on the right side. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{here}           
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{testststt} \label{tab_BG1_zustand}
  \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
        \toprule
        Zustandsgröße &  Beziehung \\ \midrule 
       {$\!\begin{aligned} 
           &\text{spezifisches Volumen} \\ 
           & $v = (\partial g / \partial p)_T} \end{aligned}$}
           & $v(\pi,\tau)\frac{p}{R T} = \pie \gamma_{\pi}$ \\ \vspace{5mm} \\
        {$\!\begin{aligned}
            &\text{spezifische innere Energie} \\
            & $u=g-T(\partial g / \partial T)_p - p(\partial g / \partial p)_T \end{aligned}$}
            & $\frac{u(\pi,\tau )}{R T} = \tau \gamma_{\tau}$ \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Since it's in an aligned environment, I thought that I would get equation numbers on the right. However, there are none.
I think it's because aligned is a non-math environment, so I don't get equation numbers for the inline math; but if I exchange it with align I can't really get it to work.

**Update**
I edited the code according to Bernard's answer, but with the intent to number the right equation:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{testststt} \label{tab_BG1_zustand}
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
        \toprule
        Zustandsgröße &  Beziehung \\ \midrule 
        {$\!\begin{aligned} 
           &\text{spezifisches Volumen} \\ 
           &$v = (\partial g / \partial p)_T} \end{aligned}$}
   & \begin{equation}v(\pi,\tau)\frac{p}{R T} = \pie \gamma_{\pi}  \end{equation} \\ \vspace{5mm} \\
        {$\!\begin{aligned}
            &\text{spezifische innere Energie} \\
            &$u=g-T(\partial g / \partial T)_p - p(\partial g / \partial p)_T \end{aligned}$}
            & \begin{equation}\frac{u(\pi,\tau )}{R T} = \tau \gamma_{\tau} \end{equation} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It now looks like this:
[image: Example]

However, the right equations are too low - I want them to be in the middle of the cell (see original example).

Comment: `aligned` *is* a math environment, but it's a "subsidiary" environment.  subsidiary environments never get numbers.  where do you want the number?  at the far right, as if just the rightmost equation is an ordinary numbered equation?

Comment: (a) There are lots of syntax errors. (b) I do not see any alignments, which equations should be aligned where? (c) It is pretty unclear, where you want to have equation numbers. (d) `aligned` does not set equation numbers unlike `align` or `alignat`.

Comment: I would want the equation numbers at the far right, just as you described barbara. It's very possible that there are many syntax errors, I started working with Latex two days ago and I'm still a bit overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `m`-type columns and `flalign` for left aligning the numbered equation. Some vertical space corrections are needed, but they're hidden in a macro, so you don't need to specify them each time.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\tableequation}[1]{%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
  {\begin{flalign}#1&&&\end{flalign}}%
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

With a reference to one of the equations, \eqref{eq-sV}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering

\caption{testststt} \label{tab_BG1_zustand}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\linespread{1.2}\selectfont}m{6cm}
  @{}
  m{6cm}
  @{}
}
\toprule
Zustandsgröße &  Beziehung \\
\midrule 

spezifisches Volumen\newline
$v = (\partial g / \partial p)_T$ &
  \tableequation{
    v(\pi,\tau)\frac{p}{R T} = \pi \gamma_{\pi} \label{eq-sV}
  } \\

spezifische innere Energie\newline
$u=g-T(\partial g / \partial T)_p - p(\partial g / \partial p)_T$ &
  \tableequation{
    \frac{u(\pi,\tau )}{R T} = \tau \gamma_{\tau}
  } \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some variations of Kormylo's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244616/16967):

- The cells in the left column uses an inner `tabular`.
  The second line is indented to emphasize the term in the first line.
- No fixed column widths.
- The equation numbers can be referenced, using `amsmath` macros for the formatting of the equation number.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{testststt}
  \label{tab_BG1_zustand}
  \newcommand*{\SetEqNum}{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \thetag\theequation
  }
  \newcommand*{\DisplayEq}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{\displaystyle #1}%
  }
  \newcommand*{\DefEq}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}%
      #1\\
      \quad\DisplayEq{#2}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \begin{tabular}{llr}
    \toprule
    Zustandsgröße &  Beziehung
    \\ \midrule
    \DefEq{spezifisches Volumen}{v = (\partial g / \partial p)_T}
    & \DisplayEq{v(\pi,\tau)\frac{p}{R T} = \pi \gamma_{\pi}}
    & \SetEqNum\label{eq:Volumen}
    \\
    \addlinespace
    \DefEq{spezifische innere Energie}
          {u=g-T(\partial g / \partial T)_p - p(\partial g / \partial p)_T}
    & \DisplayEq{\frac{u(\pi,\tau )}{R T} = \tau \gamma_{\tau}}
    & \SetEqNum\label{eq:InnereEnergie}
    \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

In der Tabelle~\ref{tab_BG1_zustand} gibt es die Beziehungen
\eqref{eq:Volumen} und~\eqref{eq:InnereEnergie}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

The p{6cm} is equivalent to \parbox[t]{6cm}, but \parbox[c]{6cm} would do better for this.  Nor do you really need a display math environment when $\displaystyle ...$ will do.  Especially, if you put the equation number into its own column.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath} 
\usepackage{here}           
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listliketab}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{testststt} \label{tab_BG1_zustand}
  \begin{tabular}{llr}
        \toprule
        Zustandsgröße &  Beziehung \\ \midrule 
       \parbox[c]{6cm}{\text{spezifisches Volumen} \newline
         $\displaystyle v = (\partial g / \partial p)_T$}
        & \parbox[c]{6cm}{$\displaystyle v(\pi,\tau)\frac{p}{R T} = \pi \gamma_{\pi}$}
        & \stepcounter{equation}(\theequation) 
        \\[5mm]
       \parbox[c]{6cm}{\text{spezifische innere Energie} \newline
         $\displaystyle u=g-T(\partial g / \partial T)_p - p(\partial g / \partial p)_T$}
        & \parbox[c]{6cm}{$\displaystyle \frac{u(\pi,\tau )}{R T} = \tau \gamma_{\tau}$}
        & \stepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
        \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: taqbular]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. I used `threeparttable` in order to have the caption  left-aligned w.r.t. the table. Off topic: you shouldn't load `here` since `float` defines an `H` option.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[intlimits]{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, caption, threeparttable}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\fleqn}m{#1} <{\endfleqn}}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{testststt} \label{tab_BG1_zustand}
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{-2ex}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{-1.5ex}
    \begin{tabular}{M{6cm} M{6cm}}
      \toprule
      Zustandsgröße & Beziehung \\ \midrule
      \begin{fleqn}\begin{gather*}
      \shortintertext{spezifisches Volumen}
      v =(∂ g / ∂ T)_T\end{gather*}\vskip-\abovedisplayskip\end{fleqn}
                      & \begin{equation}\displaystyle v(π,τ)\frac{p}{R T} = π e γ_{π}\end{equation} \\
      \begin{fleqn}\begin{gather*}
      \shortintertext{spezifische innere Energie}
      u = g- T (∂ g / ∂ T)_p- p(∂ g / ∂ T)_T \end{gather*}\end{fleqn}
                      & \begin{equation}
      \frac{u(π, τ)}{RT} = τ γ_{τ}
      \end{equation}\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to number the right most equation and see the equation number on the far right. I tried moving the \begin{equation} to the right formula, but it messed with the formatting. Also, and this is different in your solution, the right equation should be in the vertical center of the right cell. Right now it's on the same height as the left equation.

Comment: I photoshopped a picture for clarification: [like this](http://i.imgur.com/TPxxU7k.png)

Comment: @Phil Nope: I adjusted my code. Should be like you want now.